# POST Parse.Cloud.httpRequest with x-www-form-urlencoded fails with SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I’m trying to execute the following Parse.Cloud.httpRequest request as part of a credit card registration (tokenisation) process:

```js
var cardRegistrationResponse = Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: 'POST',
    url: cardRegistrationURL,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: {
        'accessKeyRef': accessKey,
        'cardNumber': cardInfo.number,
        'cardExpirationDate': cardInfo.expirationDate,
        'cardCvx': cardInfo.cvx,
        'data': preRegistrationData
    }
});
```

as part of a Parse Cloud function that I call in my iOS application using PFCloud.callFunction. But the Parse.Cloud side of thing seems to fail when doing the request (log stop right after logging all the body parameter values. See below) and the iOS side reports the following error:

```
2015-12-17 11:32:47.494 Nestor[37909:5680550] [Error]: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in <unknown file>:1 (Code: 141, Version: 1.11.0)
```

Here the cloud console log dumping the body parameters:

```
I2015-12-17T10:32:46.363Z]cardNumber: 4970100000000154
I2015-12-17T10:32:46.364Z]cardExpirationDate: 0417
I2015-12-17T10:32:46.365Z]cardCvx: 123
I2015-12-17T10:32:46.366Z]data: Qi7oou23Q8d9B3xUpjdMuYgoy_1_mCBE34uqPb7mkAmJqHGBx4ZVlLNGNPFiFYaJS4wCy-yiraxeE65tmxOe8A
I2015-12-17T10:32:46.367Z]typeof accessKeyRef is string
I2015-12-17T10:32:46.368Z]typeof cardNumber is string
I2015-12-17T10:32:46.369Z]typeof expirationDate is string
I2015-12-17T10:32:46.370Z]typeof cardCvx is string
I2015-12-17T10:32:46.371Z]typeof data is string
```

I have no clue what is going on. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

So to put things in context, here is the complete Parse.Cloud function:

```js
// Register a credit card for a later use.
//
// Request params may include: 
// - 'credentials': a JSON object with a bearer 'access_token'
//
// Request params must include a 'cardInfo' dictionary with the following keys:
// - 'paymentUserId': the card owner user id in the payment platform
// - 'number': the card number 
// - 'expirationDate': the card expiration date in format 'MMYY'
// - 'cvx': the card security code in the format 'NNN'
// - 'currency': the card currency 3-letter code, eg 'EUR'
// - 'type': the card type, one of 'CB_VISA_MASTERCARD', 'DINERS', or 'MAESTRO'
// 
// Returns a JSON object that contains the registered card info:
// - 'cardId': the id of the registered card in the payment platform
// - 'partialNumber': the partially obfuscated card number
// - 'expirationDate': the card expiration date in the format 'MMYY'
// - 'provider': the card provider, one of 'VISA', 'MASTERCARD'...
Parse.Cloud.define("registerCard", function(request, response) {
 
 var credentials = request.params.credentials;
 var cardInfo = request.params.cardInfo;

 Parse.Promise.as(credentials).then(function(credentials) {
  // Make sure we have credentials

   if (typeof credentials === 'undefined') {
    return Parse.Cloud.run("authorize")
   } else {
    return Parse.Promise.as(credentials)
   }

 }).then(function(credentials) {
  // Step 1: PREREGISTRATION
   var cred = Parse.Promise.as(credentials);

   // var preCardRegistrationResponse = preCardRegistration(credentials, cardInfo);
  console.log("Pre-registration");
  console.log("CardType: " + cardInfo.type);
  console.log("Currency: " + cardInfo.currency);
  console.log("UserId: " + cardInfo.userId);

  var preCardRegistrationResponse = Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
   method: 'POST',
   url: mango_api_url + '/v2/sbsquare2015/cardRegistrations',
   headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + credentials.access_token
   },
   body: {
    'CardType': cardInfo.type,
    'Currency': cardInfo.currency,
    // mangopay user id
    'UserId': cardInfo.userId 
   }
  });

   return Parse.Promise.when(cred, preCardRegistrationResponse);

 }).then(function(credentials, preCardRegistrationResponse) {
  // Step 2: REGISTRATION
  var cred = Parse.Promise.as(credentials);
  var preCardRegistrationInfo = JSON.parse(preCardRegistrationResponse.text);

  // var cardRegistrationResponse = cardRegistration(credentials, cardInfo, preCardRegistrationInfo);
  var cardRegistrationURL = preCardRegistrationInfo.CardRegistrationURL;
  var preRegistrationData = preCardRegistrationInfo.PreregistrationData;
  var accessKey = preCardRegistrationInfo.AccessKey;

  console.log("Card registration");
  console.log("url: " + cardRegistrationURL);
  console.log("accessKeyRef: " + accessKey);
  console.log("cardNumber: " + cardInfo.number);
  console.log("cardExpirationDate: " + cardInfo.expirationDate);
  console.log("cardCvx: " + cardInfo.cvx);
  console.log("data: " + preRegistrationData);

  console.log("typeof accessKeyRef is " + (typeof accessKey) );
  console.log("typeof cardNumber is " + (typeof cardInfo.number) );
  console.log("typeof expirationDate is " + (typeof cardInfo.expirationDate) );
  console.log("typeof cardCvx is " + (typeof cardInfo.cvx) );

  console.log("typeof data is " + (typeof preRegistrationData) );
  
  var cardRegistrationResponse = Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
   method: 'POST',
   url: cardRegistrationURL,
   // Default to url form encoded
   // headers: {
   //  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
   // },
   body: {
    'accessKeyRef': accessKey,
    'cardNumber': cardInfo.number,
    'cardExpirationDate': cardInfo.expirationDate,
    'cardCvx': cardInfo.cvx,
    'data': preRegistrationData
   }
  });

  return Parse.Promise.when(cred, cardRegistrationResponse);

 }).then(function(credentials, cardRegistrationResponse) {
  // Step 3: POSTREGISTRATION
  var cardRegistrationInfo = JSON.parse(cardRegistrationResponse.text);

  // var postCardRegistrationResponse = postCardRegistration(credentials, cardRegistrationInfo);
  var cardId = cardRegistrationInfo.Id;

  var postCardRegistration = Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
   method: 'PUT',
   url: mango_api_url + '/v2/sbsquare2015/cardRegistration/' + cardId,
   headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
   },
   body: cardRegistrationInfo
  });

  return postCardRegistrationResponse;

 }).then(function(postCardRegistrationResponse) {
  // TRANSFORMATION
  var cardRegistrationInfo = JSON.parse(postCardRegistrationResponse.text);
  console.log("cardId: " + cardRegistrationInfo.CardId);
  console.log("expirationDate: " + cardInfo.expirationDate);
  console.log("provider: " + cardRegistrationInfo.CardProvider);

  var registeredCard = {
   'cardId': cardRegistration.CardId,
   'partialNumber': cardInfo.number.slice(0, 6) + '******' + cardInfo.number.slice(12, 16),
   'expirationDate': cardInfo.expirationDate,
   'provider': cardRegistrationInfo.CardProvider
  } 

  return Parse.Promise.as(registeredCard);

  }).then(function(registeredCard) {

   console.log("Registered card " + registeredCard);
   response.success(registeredCard);

  }, function(error) {

   console.log("Card registration failed: " + error);
   response.error(error);
   
  });
});
```

Side note: I have the whole card registration tested in Paw and also in an iOS Swift client but I'm trying to implement it on the server side so I don't have to write an Android client as well...

But the cloud version stop during step 2 and I get the error mentioned above in my iOS client when calling the Parse Cloud function 'registerCard'.

sidenote: I'm not sure I'm using Promise the right way. I would expect the last error function to be called but it is not...

Thanks for your help

B

Comment: you'll need to show more code than that...

Comment: @Wain anything you need ! Code coming your way...

Comment: Please somebody help me or I'm gonna commit the 'irreparable' and spoil Star Wars VII for all of you guys !!!... Ok I'm kidding but that how desperate I am

Comment: What version of the jssdk are you using ?

Comment: @Wain 1.6.7, the latest

Comment: so it looks like one of the responses isn't actually JSON then...

Comment: @Wain Thank You ! Oh gosh... step 2 got through but the response indeed is not JSON... Need a new pair of eyes (or a new brain...)